# addClass every nth

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I have a list of elements that I want to style in 3 different ways.

I want every 3rd list item to have the same class throughout the whole list.

For example:

```
<li class="A">Some Content</li>
<li class="B">Some Content</li>
<li class="C">Some Content</li>
<li class="A">Some Content</li>
<li class="B">Some Content</li>
<li class="C">Some Content</li>
<li class="A">Some Content</li>
<li class="B">Some Content</li>
<li class="C">Some Content</li>
```

I can do 2 with :odd/even, but how to do it with 3?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

try

```
$("ul li:nth-child(3n+1)").addClass("A")
$("ul li:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("B")
$("ul li:nth-child(3n)").addClass("C")
```

Feel free to consolidate it to make it prettier, but I wanted to expose the selectors.

Comment: To make this a working solution use: $('ul li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('every-third-item-class');

Comment: @brownstone - see the edit, I changed it to address his total concern (albeit longhanded)

Comment: Thanks Marc. This was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Marc - To be honest I was just being picky about the missing single-quotes :) although pointing out the +n notation makes the answer complete.

Comment: @brownstone - woops!  good eye, missed those.  @davebowker - glad I could help

Comment: Great fix @Marc. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I recommend something like this:

```
let i = 0;
$("li").each(function() {
    i++;
    let newClass = 'A';
    if (i % 3 == 1) { newClass = 'B'; }
    if (i % 3 == 2) { newClass = 'C'; }
    $(this).addClass(newClass);
});
```

Comment: this does not work... delete first line and add the "i" in ....each(function(i)....

Comment: I fixed the code. Also updated it to use let instead of global scope var.