# jQuery target every nth sibling of an element

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have following markup:

```
<div class="region">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="region">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
```

How can I target the 3rd element after .region so that I get something like this?

```
<div class="region">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="region">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="award third">
<div class="award">
<div class="award">
<div class="award third">
```

Note that it is not counting the first two .award elements after first .region.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260277/addclass-every-nth

Comment: @Armatus: I don't think so, not with the varying starting points.

Comment: These divs are meant to be *siblings*, right? You haven't closed them, which means you have eight layers of children there, but I'm sure that's not what you meant...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder True, a slight difference I did not fully notice. Please regard my comment as a reading suggestion for ideas in that case :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`nextUntil` combined with `eq` should do it:</s>

```
$("div.region").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(":not(.award)").eq(2).addClass("third");
});
```

Nope, a *little* more complicated than that, to handle the 6th element:

```
$("div.region").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(":not(.award)").filter(function(index) {
        return index % 3 == 2;
    }).addClass("third");
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/awiqut/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/awiqut/2/edit)

There we grab each of the `.region` elements, get their siblings up to the first one that isn't an `.award` ([`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil)), and [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) out ones that aren't every third one.

*(Not sure why I used [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) in my [first working copy](http://jsbin.com/awiqut), `filter` makes much more sense.)*

Comment: making the assumption that each of the div is actually not nested and are closed, (bad markup in example from OP) this would not select the 10th (last) div as a second "3rd" element.

Comment: Yep, i was looking at the original as it seemed to not suffice :) had to study it a bit :)  Check this one off as working now.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Yeah, I facepalmed a bit when I did the live example. And I just realized that even in the fix, I used `map` where `filter` would be the more appropriate choice, so I've fixed that too.

Comment: Yes, that is better, but they both work.  Makes me wonder which is faster :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: Oh, wave the red flag why don't you. ;-) Looks like `filter`, which probably shouldn't surprise us: http://jsperf.com/silly-map-vs-filter