# Add a div every X element using JQ or CSS

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

I have numerous divs, lets say 10, and i wanna add a new div with a specific class every 4th element.
can anyone please tell me how can i do it using JQ or CSS? i prefer JQ because i wanna make it dynamic.

Thanks ahead! and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260277/addclass-every-nth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<div/>').addClass('someclassname').html('somehtml').insertAfter('div:nth-child(4n)');​
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rjW7u/)

Answer (score 0):

@AshirvadSingh solution is offcourse correct and probably the best solution. Just to be complte though, you could actualy do it with pure css. Technicaly you don't actually insert a new div, but the effect would be the same, and you would have all the same styling options. The css would look like this:

```
div:nth-child(4n):after {
   content: 'b';
   display: block;
   color: green;   
}
```

I updated @AshirvadSingh fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/rjW7u/1/

The advantage of the jQuery solution is that it would probably work better in older browser that do not support the pseudo selectors i used. The css solution on the other hand would still work for people that have js disabled.