# Jquery Isotope Filtering with "nth-child"

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope, css-selectors

I've seen a similar question but doesn't really solves my issue. So here's the thing:

I'm using Jquery Isotope to filter my "items". Every items has a margin-right:2.2% except every fourth item,  i've used :nth-child(4n) to remove a margin for every fourth item.

So everything looks good until i "filter" my  items,  it doesn't add CSS to the newly filtered items but uses the old one.

How do I apply these CSS options even on the filtered items?

P.S.

I hope it makes sense :s

Comment: Maybe you can select 'em better if you  add a class like  [here][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260277/addclass-every-nth

Comment: hmm i'll take a look thanks.
My main problem is after filtering the applied margin is not changing.
before that everything works fine.

Comment: Hm, sorry, I dont get it. What exactly are you trying? Could you post your code? Maybe what you need is an on change function like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418963/jquery-onchange-function-not-triggering-for-dynamically-created-inputs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XCTrv/ (basic markup)

So basicly what happens is this: I have lets say 8 items that can be filtered, every 4th item  has margin-right set to 0, while others have 2.21% margin.

BUT if you "click" on filter it doesen't apply the CSS to the newly filtered "list", So if the item that has been  4th in the list, becomes let's say second in the list after filtering, it will keep the CSS form the original markup, and will  have margin-right:0; instead of margin-right:2.21%;
So what i'm trying to do is to add the same CSS rules to the filtered layout via some jquery or what not.

Comment: ah now that i had a look at that isotope demo: http://www.9bitstudios.com/demos/blog/jquery-isotope/ I know what it is supposed to do. Well I would guess you have to create a on change function for "#item-container" where you add a css changing function that looks like this (pseudocode): $( "#item-container li").css({"margin":"2.2%"});" ) $( "#item-container li:nth-child(4)").css({"margin":"0"});" ) Delete your css and add these two lines after a document ready. Maybe that will work