# How to add a class for every second div in a row

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add one class for every second item in a row, please help, 
  Thanks in advance

Adding some dummy content to fulfill its criteria

```
<?php $counter = 1 ?> 
     <div class="services-posts mt2 pull-right">
      <?php
       $args = array( 'post_type' => 'services');
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url('full');  ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4 <?php if ($counter % 2 == 0) : ?> animation-fadeInUp <?php endif; ?> <?php if ($counter % 1 == 0) : ?> animation-fadeInLeft <?php endif; ?> <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0) : ?> animation-fadeInRight <?php endif; ?> "  >
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
                    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                    /*I need to add a class to the each second box-div2 div */
                     <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"   class="box-div2">
                     <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="c-div">
                        <a href="">
                            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                            <span>
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                            </span>
                    </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <?php if ($counter % 3 == 0){echo '</div><div class="services-posts mt2 pull-right">';} ?> 
                  <?php $counter++ ; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260277/addclass-every-nth)

Comment: that is a solution using jquery, and my one is php

Comment: What is currently happening when you run the code?

Comment: I need a class on every second element for this class
    <div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"   class="box-div2">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, I have created a variable $divclass which will add the class accordingly.

Replace:

```
/*I need to add a class to the each second box-div2 div */
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"   class="box-div2">
```

With:

```
<?php 
    $divclass="";
    if ($counter%2==0) {
        $divclass="box-div2";
    }
?>
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')"   class="<?php echo $divclass;?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to every second query result? If so this should work:

```
<?php $div2_class = $counter % 2 == 0 ? 'your-class' : ''; ?>
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')" class="box-div2 <?php echo $div2_class; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

As a rough all-things solution, you can use the [ternary](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) operator plus the [modulo](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator:

```
<?php echo (($counter % 2 == 0) ? $theThingYouWantToEcho : null) ?>
```

The code inside the brackets says:

- if `$counter / 2` is a whole number (has no remainder when divided)
- then return `$theThingYouWantToEcho`
- else return null (nothing)

The echo statement will then print out the result of that.

You could replace `$theThingYouWantToEcho` with the CSS class you want to add

i.e.

```
<div class="<?php echo (($counter % 2 == 0) ? 'myClass' : null) ?>">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not what's your reason to do this is, but if it's for styling purposes CSS allows you to select even/odd elements:

```
a:nth-child(odd) {
    background: green;
}

a:nth-child(even) {
    background: red;
}
```

Using a formula `(an + b)` you can even use other cycles, not just odd/even.

On the other hand if it's for programmatic reasons jQuery has odd/even selectors too:

```
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "green");
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "red");
```

So generally you don't need classes to separate odd/even elements.